# Powershell Decimal Format without comma

Tags: powershell

How can I format powershell output for decimal without a comma?
I am using '{0:N2}' -f $a but I don't want the comma for the thousands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a plethora of different format strings. In your case I would suggest:

> '{0:d2}' -f $a

A good reference is [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Actually here are some examples:

```
$a = 124000.4201

 '{0:g2}' -f $a
1.2e+05

'{0:f2}' -f $a
124000.42

# and since it is using the .net formatter for all this after all
'{0:00.0000}' -f $a
124000.4201
```

Comment: then you probably used '{0:d2}' and your data has decimal values. I didn't notice that in your original post. Try '{0:f2}'

Answer (score 1):

Try using .net class:

```
[string]::Format("{0:0.00}" ,$a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code snippet below:

```
'{0:N2}' -f $a | foreach {$_.replace(",","") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 0 for the precision specifier

```
PS> $a = 123.456
PS> '{0:N0}' -f 123.456
123
```

You can also cast to int:

```
PS> [int]$a
123
```

Or use a regex to get any character until the dot

```
PS> $a -replace '^([^.]+).+','$1'
123
```

or using split:

```
PS> "$a".split('.')[0]
123
```

or math...

```
PS> [math]::Floor($a)
123
```

And there are a lot of other ways.

Comment: "Or use a regex to get any character until the dot" -- But then you have two problems.  (That never gets old)

Comment: It's a classic if possibly obscure quote: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: Realize that I do not use it because I want to slight regexs, I love them and use them all the time. I just think it's funny :)

Comment: I wasn't sure it was a joke, my poor English ;), thanks for the pointer

Comment: Your english is way better than my Hebrew.