# Powershell Decimal D command or manual maths

Tags: excel, math, powershell, decimal

Powershell script .ps1
Excel

Issue: It's in the script

```
#CALCULATE FREE MEMORY AS PERCENTAGE

#DECLARE VARIABLES
#MY CURRENT FREE SERVER MEM
$currentMem = ([math]::round($freemem.FreePhysicalMemory / 1024, 2))
#MY SERVER MEM LIMIT
$maxMemLimit = 16000
#MY FINAL FREE MEM VALUE PERCENTAGE VARIABLE HOLDER
$freeMemPerc = 0

#MY WORKING OUT
$freeMemPerc = ($maxMemLimit / $currentMem)

#I CAN ADD THIS LINE BELOW OR LEAVE IT OUT IF I USE THE NUMBER FORMAT TYPES (DECIMAL)
#CURRENTLY IT'S COMMENTED
#$freeMemPerc = 100 * $freeMemPerc

#ADD TO SPREADSHEET
#USING THE DECIMAL D CMD TO FORMAT THE NUMBER
"Free Memory (% of MB total): {0:D}" -f $freeMemPerc
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Free Memory (% of MB total):"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "$freeMemPerc %"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
```

Scenario:
I am trying to turn server values of MB and GB into percentages based on server limit. Let's say my current server usage is: 2617.89mb, I should get the answer in my spreadsheet as: 16.3618125

Based on math: 2617.89 / 16000 * 100.

Current result I receive is 6.11. I have tried adding other decimals or decreasing decimals to D too but still don't get my answer.

I think my programming is wrong here not my maths, although in reality my maths is terrible.

Any ideas?

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx

Comment: Saw this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218060/powershell-decimal-format-without-comma but no success.

Comment: If the expected result is 15.625 and you're getting 15.625, what is the problem?

Comment: Hahah silly me, Sorry I've updated and used current values.

Comment: pnuts, I've tried that and I get a different value, 0.14% for current Free space of 2287.11. I think the issue is the number formatting. Error: 'Format specifier was invalid'. I can tell {0.0} is better than {0.D} but I think it should be something else which is similar.

Comment: Oh and for the smarties my last comment is still indicating an error with the percentage value format, not the result 0.14% as this is right as far as 2287.11 usage is concerned.

Comment: No luck @pnuts, this gives us 7 decimal places and the result based on 2557.72 is 0.1598575 it should be either 15.98 or 15.985 or etc. depending on how many decimal places I need. Thanks again though.

Comment: Thanks to pnuts, because like normal maths you don't have to, but better to divide smaller number with the bigger number
#also in PS, you can do your maths has priority if in parenthesis
#I've also learned this from other sites that this is true
#So all I have here is my currentMem divided by maxMemLimit
#Add it to freeMemPer variable

Comment: $freeMemPer = ($currentMem/$maxMemLimit)

Comment: #The number in freeMemPer is multiplied by 100
#Then equlas to our variable freeMemPer but the number is also added to freeMemPer

Comment: $freeMemPer += ($freeMemPer * 100)

Comment: #Call our variable freeMemPer
#Format using the default 0 number format to display whather the results is, as is.
#e.g. if freeMemPer holds the number 16.000, it will display 16.000
#This is better instead of using {0:P0} percentage format 
#As for some reason it doesn't like it

Comment: "Free Memory (% of MB total): {0}" -f $freeMemPer

Comment: Am sure it can all be done using the {0:D) or {0:P7} decimal and percentage formats! Which would save lines of code!

Comment: I fixed this by using this syntax:                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                            #TOTAL MEM IN SYSTEM
"Total Physical Memory: {0}" -f ([math]::truncate($phyMem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1MB))
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Total Physical Memory (MB):"       $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = ([math]::truncate($phyMem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1MB))

Comment: #TOTAL MEM AVAIL TO SYSTEM
"Total Usable Memory: {0}" -f ([math]::round($freemem.TotalVisibleMemorySize / 1024, 2))
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Total Usable Memory (MB):"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = ([math]::round($freemem.TotalVisibleMemorySize / 1024, 2))

Comment: #TOTAL MEM USED
$totalMemUsed     = (([math]::round($freemem.TotalVisibleMemorySize / 1024, 2)) - ([math]::round($freemem.FreePhysicalMemory / 1024, 2)))
$totalFreeMemLeft = ($totalMemUsed - ([math]::round($freemem.TotalVisibleMemorySize / 1MB)))

Comment: #TOTAL FREE PHYSICAL MEM LEFT (TOTAL MEM AVAIL TO SYSTEM - TOTALUSED)
"Free Memory (MB): {0}" -f $totalFreeMemLeft #([math]::round($totalFreeMemLeft.FreePhysicalMemory / 1024, 2))
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Free Memory (MB):"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $totalFreeMemLeft

Comment: Hope it helps others! Thanks, ParttimeCoder